# Why isn't Gson parsing my document with nested escaped JSON string?

Tags: java, json, gson, resttemplate

I'm having an annoying problem with GSON.

I can't get this document to parse:

```
[{"id":0,"assetId":2414775,"shipId":717,"assetType":"0","document":"{\"ratios\":[{\"points\":{\"x1\":0,\"y1\":673,\"x2\":3744,\"y2\":4408},\"crop\":[{\"name\":\"1_1\",\"width\":3744,\"height\":3735,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_1_1.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-supersquare\",\"width\":1024,\"height\":1024,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_x-supersquare.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-square\",\"width\":98,\"height\":98,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_x-square.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x48\",\"width\":48,\"height\":48,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_x48.jpg\"}],\"name\":\"1_1\",\"basename\":null,\"cropped\":true},{\"points\":{\"x1\":0,\"y1\":842,\"x2\":3744,\"y2\":3650},\"crop\":[{\"name\":\"4_3\",\"width\":3744,\"height\":2808,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_4_3.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-superlarge\",\"width\":2048,\"height\":1536,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_x-superlarge.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-extralarge\",\"width\":1024,\"height\":768,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_x-extralarge.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-large\",\"width\":490,\"height\":368,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_x-large.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x\",\"width\":245,\"height\":184,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_x.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x86\",\"width\":115,\"height\":86,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121019_x86.jpg\"}],\"name\":\"4_3\",\"basename\":null,\"cropped\":true},{\"points\":{\"x1\":0,\"y1\":322,\"x2\":3744,\"y2\":5307},\"crop\":[{\"name\":\"3_4\",\"width\":3744,\"height\":4985,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121020_3_4.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-3-4\",\"width\":768,\"height\":1024,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121020_x-3-4.jpg\"}],\"name\":\"3_4\",\"basename\":null,\"cropped\":true},{\"points\":{\"x1\":0,\"y1\":1755,\"x2\":3744,\"y2\":3861},\"crop\":[{\"name\":\"16_9\",\"width\":3744,\"height\":2106,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121020_16_9.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-16-9super\",\"width\":2048,\"height\":1162,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121020_x-16-9super.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-16-9\",\"width\":1280,\"height\":720,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121020_x-16-9.jpg\"}],\"name\":\"16_9\",\"basename\":null,\"cropped\":true},{\"points\":{\"x1\":295,\"y1\":0,\"x2\":3448,\"y2\":5616},\"crop\":[{\"name\":\"9_16\",\"width\":3153,\"height\":5616,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121020_9_16.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-9-16\",\"width\":720,\"height\":1280,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121020_x-9-16.jpg\"}],\"name\":\"9_16\",\"basename\":null,\"cropped\":true},{\"points\":{\"x1\":0,\"y1\":1221,\"x2\":3744,\"y2\":4408},\"crop\":[{\"name\":\"front_thumb\",\"width\":3744,\"height\":3187,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121021_front_thumb.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"x-front-thumb\",\"width\":115,\"height\":98,\"path\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas-1306121021_x-front-thumb.jpg\"}],\"name\":\"front_thumb\",\"basename\":null,\"cropped\":true}],\"attributes\":[{\"name\":\"oImageHeight\",\"value\":\"5616\"},{\"name\":\"oImageWidth\",\"value\":\"3744\"},{\"name\":\"sImageHeight\",\"value\":\"400\"},{\"name\":\"sImageWidth\",\"value\":\"266\"},{\"name\":\"imageCropStatus\",\"value\":\"1_1:manual;  4_3:manual;  3_4:manual;  16_9:manual;  9_16:manual;  front_thumb:manual;  \"},{\"name\":\"credit\",\"value\":\"Michel Verdure\"},{\"name\":\"alternate\",\"value\":\"Image of Royal Caribbean Allure of the Sease\"},{\"name\":\"title\",\"value\":\"Allure of the Seas\"},{\"name\":\"caption\",\"value\":\"Allure of the Seas - At sea,  by the coast line of Miami\\nAllure of the Seas - Royal Caribbean International\"},{\"name\":\"datephototaken\",\"value\":\"11-24-2010\"},{\"name\":\"cutline\",\"value\":\"Allure of the Seas - At sea,  by the coast line of Miami\\nAllure of the Seas - Royal Caribbean International\"},{\"name\":\"orientation\",\"value\":\"horizontal\"},{\"name\":\"OrigImageName\",\"value\":\"RCI Allure of the Seas.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"imgIndex\",\"value\":\"1371046546001\"},{\"name\":\"imgUniqueName\",\"value\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"isImageVisitedByUser\",\"value\":\"True\"},{\"name\":\"isAutoCroppedSetOn\",\"value\":\"True\"},{\"name\":\"publishurl\",\"value\":\"http://www.gannett-cdn.com/media\"},{\"name\":\"rootpath\",\"value\":\"/TEST/GenericImages/2013/06/12/\"},{\"name\":\"basename\",\"value\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas.jpg\"},{\"name\":\"smallbasename\",\"value\":\"1371046546001-RCI-Test-Seas_small.jpg\"}],\"contributors\":[],\"id\":2414775,\"propertyID\":1,\"siteid\":1,\"sitename\":\"TEST\",\"assetGroupId\":1,\"assetGroupName\":\"TEST\",\"type\":\"image\",\"typeid\":1,\"typeidSpecified\":true,\"position\":0,\"positionSpecified\":true,\"priority\":null,\"handling\":null,\"status\":\"published\",\"dates\":{\"embargodate\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00-05:00\",\"feeddateline\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00-05:00\"},\"TaxonomyEntities\":[],\"assetdocument\":null,\"lastaction\":null,\"CreateDate\":\"2013-06-12T10:19:15.607-04:00\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2013-06-12T10:19:39-04:00\",\"CreateUser\":\"nrifken\",\"UpdateUser\":\"nrifken\",\"LastPublishedDate\":\"2013-06-12T10:19:15.607-04:00\"}"}]
```

You can use an online tool to view it better (i.e. http://json.parser.online.fr/)

As you can see the "document" is a nested JSON as string and somehow GSON is trying to parse that when I think it shouldn't, I tried setting my Serializable member as String, Object, Map, Map<Object, Object>, etc. but none of them seems to work. Also tried setting it to transient or removing to see if GSON wouldn't bother parsing but still I get:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 72
```

I think I don't have much control of the deserialization since I'm using RestTemplate's GsonHttpMessageConverter. so I think it's mostly e GSON issue than Springs.

My Model:

```
public class ShipAsset {

public ShipAsset(String pID, Integer pAssetID,
        Integer pShipID, String pDocument, String pAssetType) {
    super();
    mID = pID;
    mAssetID = pAssetID;
    mShipID = pShipID;
    mDocument = pDocument;
    mAssetType = pAssetType;
}

public ShipAsset() {
}

@SerializedName("id")
private String mID;

@SerializedName("assetId")
private Integer mAssetID;

@SerializedName("shipId")
private Integer mShipID;

@SerializedName("document")
private String mDocument;

@SerializedName("assetType")
private String mAssetType;

/* getters and setters */ 

}
```

That's how I'm calling it:

```
ShipAsset[] oResults = mGson.fromJson(oJSONString, ShipAsset[].class);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there! Can you show us your model classes? (That one's that you are trying to cast with Gson)

Comment: There you go! thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

The error must be in one of this three things:

1) You are receiving a JSONArray, you are casting like this don't you?:

```
public class RestFactory {

public static ShipAsset[] getShipsAssets(RestClient restClient) throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<ShipAsset[]> response = restClient.getForEntity(
            "http://server/rest/yourmethod", ShipAsset[].class);
    return response.getBody();
}

}
```

2) I'm not sure if It's by this, but you don't have a constructor with all the fields neither an empty contructor. Maybe because isn't a full pojo, Gson isn't casting rightly.

3) Try to annotate the fields `id` and `assetType`. I'm pretty sure that if you don't annotate a field with the `SerializedName` annotation, Gson ignores it by default. But anyways, give it a try!.

Good luck!

Comment: That didn't work, I tried with GSON (without RestTemplate) and it also failed... I updated the code

Comment: Well given that the error is in the column where the `document` field starts, why don't you try make a class to cast it, instead of use a String?

Comment: Thanks! figured it out, the issue was that the json document wasn't properly scaped in my string... just had to add an extra slash "\"